# stunnel can only accept on port 80, possible iptables configuration

Tags: iptables, stunnel

I am trying to get stunnel to forward from a port (eventually via https on 443) to port 8080.

The http served on 8080 is already visible correctly by a remote browser.

I have tried some 4 versions of stunnel between 4.42 - 4.55.
On Ubuntu 16 and 18.

The stunnel program output:

```
...
[!] bind: Address already in use (98)
[!] Error binding service [myhttp] to 0.0.0.0:9985
...
```

stunnel.conf (am I missing something? on the web there are various claims that this or that should be added):

```
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/<<my-domain>>/cert.pem
key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/<<my-domain>>/privkey.pem
[myhttp]
accept = 9985
connect = 8080
```

I have tried prefixing the ports with `127.0.0.1:` or `::1:`. (This has an effect in changing the 0.0.0.0 above, however same result.)

My firewall:

```
root@localhost:/home/my# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 211 packets, 160K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
145  849K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
8874 1008K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
248 24754 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
310 22151 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9985
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9986
```

If I add into /etc/services:

```
myhttp          9985/tcp
```

then the output of `iptables -L -v` contains `... tcp dpt:myhttp...`, but still 0 accepts.

If i change the entry in stunnel.conf to  `accept = 80` then the remote browser can get an https-connection through that port, and get the page served on port 8080, and it has an ssl-lock-symbol. However using port 80 for https is no solution, I need that port to serve plain http or direct the browser to the https-port.

Comment: *"Address already in use"*  - That means that something else is already listening on port  0.0.0.0:9985 - You can't have two services concurrently listen and accepting connections on the same port. Check with `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :9985` or `ss -tnlp | grep :9985` what that is.

Comment: There are various stunnels running on the ports i previously tried including 9985

Comment: and that is what we expect to see

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. My hosting provider adds another firewall outside this server, so in addition to configuring iptables, I also have to go to the provider's website and configure firewall settings there (and then they take some minutes to take effect, so be patient).

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question you posted, though!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Correct. But it is the answer I wish I had gotten. It probably will help someone who describes the same already-tried's as I have.